# How to multiply two integers using only add operator and stack

Tags: language-agnostic, stack

A friend of mine dropped me this question, I have been thinking about it but I have no clue where to even begin. The question is solvable.

Rules: You can use add, sub, conditionals, jumps and at most two stacks.

If someone has a solution, an explanation would be nice.

I already know a way to solve without stacks. `m1` and `m2` are the two numbers.

```
count = m1
prod = 0

Branch_equal_zero count,EXIT

LOOP:
prod = prod + m2
count = count - 1
Branch_not_equal_zero count,LOOP

EXIT:
return prod   
halt
```

EDIT: The program with stacks will be faster than the program above. I cant figure out how it is possible.

Comment: It seems to me like you already solved it. If you want to use an stack then instead of adding on prod, push m2 into the stack. Then include another loop that pops and sum all the elements in the stack

Comment: The idea is to make this program faster using a stack. Will your method make it faster?